# export data from hbase via shell

Tags: hbase

I m trying to export all the data from HBase Shell to a text file using shell script

I am wanting to look into a particular column in hbase and do a count of transactions that occurred and print the number in the shell script .

I am currently using the following command for exporting the data,

```
echo "scan 'registration',{COLUMNS=>'registration:status'}" | hbase shell | grep "^ " > registration.txt
```

## I want to know how to do for all the columns in the particular RowID and only the values of the column

PS: I have already went thru the link below for doing for a single column, I would like to know how I can do it for all the columns in a single command
[Export data from HBase shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208106/export-data-from-hbase-shell)

Comment: Looks like you don't want any restriction on column filter then you can simply remove {COLUMNS=>'registration:status'} part from you query and just do a simple scan . It will scan all columns for  row id's or if you want to do for particular row id then Get option is more suitable for you.

Comment: Thanks Shashi, that Worked perfectly

Comment: Can you please accept answer if is working fine for you?...

Comment: There would be check sign just below my answer. Just click on it.

Comment: thanks again for ur help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For working with particular row id with all columns , you can use below commnad

echo "get 'tablename','rowid'" | hbase shell | grep "^ " > registration.txt

Comment: This doesn't get the value. It adds the timestamp into say a pdf